# How to add 0s in place of missing months' data?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is an example of the dataframe I have:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(84, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 12, ncol = 7), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$Date <- seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), as.Date("2002/10/01"), by = "quarter")

        X1          X2         X3         X4         X5           X6          X7       Date
1  -0.22665838 -0.21435535 -0.9060361 -0.7544181  0.3697487  0.226183639 -0.35333109 2000-01-01
2   0.36459588 -0.92357903 -0.7474181  0.3930116 -0.8483455  0.001053074 -0.11071567 2000-04-01
3   0.32772746 -0.95863346 -0.2461959  0.8573144 -1.4050863 -0.851132640  0.22984387 2000-07-01
4  -1.22891784  0.59263058 -0.3155725 -0.3867662 -0.5893056 -0.246202375  0.97845330 2000-10-01
5  -0.07124602 -0.62971959 -0.1990532 -1.2540578 -0.3347652  1.061019031 -0.99044363 2001-01-01
6   1.01317419  1.18537830  0.6241457 -1.4412657 -0.3241036  0.900829237  0.06419316 2001-04-01
7   0.28590272 -1.25413779 -0.4076524  1.0633591 -0.3921616 -0.231332349 -0.82489456 2001-07-01
8  -0.83591105  0.39544445 -1.1275454 -0.8467141 -0.1827673  0.650371871  0.68155623 2001-10-01
9  -0.14689026  0.76575239 -2.3750439 -0.1958910  0.3578670  0.064873489  0.32252314 2002-01-01
10  1.26846657 -0.04560596 -0.9959704  0.3926218 -1.7770232  1.202433913 -0.05919982 2002-04-01
11 -2.01557623 -0.23142037  0.8722606 -0.1013923 -0.9775133 -1.463026339 -0.72456546 2002-07-01
12  0.30603648 -0.24289366 -1.0580142  0.8721441  2.0560490  1.357803811  0.36357346 2002-10-01
```

What I would like to do is to add 0s in the missing month rows (**note that in the "fake" dataset the frequency is quarterly but in the real one there is no regularity**). Ideally, I would achieve this:

```
        X1          X2         X3         X4         X5           X6          X7       Date
1  -0.22665838 -0.21435535 -0.9060361 -0.7544181  0.3697487  0.226183639 -0.35333109 2000-01-01
2   0             0           0              0        0         0               0    2000-02-01
3   0             0            0              0        0         0              0    2000-03-01
4   0.36459588 -0.92357903 -0.7474181  0.3930116 -0.8483455  0.001053074 -0.11071567 2000-04-01
5   0                 0           0          0        0         0              0     2000-05-01
6   0                 0           0          0         0       0               0     2000-06-01
7   0.32772746 -0.95863346 -0.2461959  0.8573144 -1.4050863 -0.851132640  0.22984387 2000-07-01
8    0             0                0         0         0         0           0      2000-08-01
9    0             0                  0       0         0         0           0      2000-09-01
10  -1.22891784  0.59263058 -0.3155725 -0.3867662 -0.5893056 -0.246202375  0.97845330 2000-10-01
#and so on and so forth
```

I know how to do this for just two columns (a column Date and a column of data):

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date, "%Y-%m-%d")),
       Month = format(Date, "%m"),
       Year = format(Date, "%Y"))  %>% 
  complete(Month = formatC(1:12, 1, flag=0), nesting(Year)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = if_else(is.na(Date), as.Date(paste(Year, Month, "1", sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d"), Date))%>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  select(Date, Nameofthecolumn) %>% 
  mutate(Columnname = if_else(is.na(Columname), 0, Columname)) %>% 
  mutate(Columnname = if_else(is.na(Columname), 0, Columname))
```

Basically I need to get a monthly frequency (from irregular frequency), where the month is absent I want a 0 for all the columns in the df.

I don't manage to do for several columns as in my case.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You can use the `fill` option in `complete`.  Also, not clear why the 'Columname' step for `ifelse` is repeated.  For multiple columns, use `mutate_at(vars(colsofinterest), replace_na, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to `fill` the columns 'X1' to 'X7' as 0, there is an option in `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
nm1 <- grep("^X\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE)
df %>% 
   mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date, "%Y-%m-%d")),
   Month = format(Date, "%m"),
   Year = format(Date, "%Y"))  %>% 
   complete(Month = formatC(1:12, 1, flag=0), nesting(Year),
        fill =  setNames(rep(list(0), 7), nm1)) %>%
   mutate(Date = if_else(is.na(Date), as.Date(paste(Year, Month, "1", 
         sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d"), Date)) %>%
   arrange(Date)
# A tibble: 36 x 10
#   Month Year     X1     X2    X3      X4     X5      X6     X7 Date      
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <date>    
# 1 01    2000  0.292 -0.942 -1.07 -0.0408  0.352  0.217   1.43  2000-01-01
# 2 02    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-02-01
# 3 03    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-03-01
# 4 04    2000  0.130 -0.722 -1.01 -0.400  -0.786 -1.43   -1.49  2000-04-01
# 5 05    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-05-01
# 6 06    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-06-01
# 7 07    2000  0.121  0.212  1.03 -1.31    0.138  2.07    0.957 2000-07-01
# 8 08    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-08-01
# 9 09    2000  0      0      0     0       0      0       0     2000-09-01
#10 10    2000  1.19   1.69   1.81  0.826  -1.20   0.0954  0.441 2000-10-01
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: you are a real master man!  Impressive as always! Thanks so much, it works perfectly! I will mark as the correct answer once stackoverflows allows me to do so shortly. Thanks again!